# Using methods that rely on other methods

Tags: java, methods, netbeans

I am trying to make a program that tells you the minimum number of coins needed to make change and it must be modular. Currently it is asking for input three times and printing the number of coins needed for the sum of all three inputs. I believe this is because of the fact that maxDimes relies on maxQuarters which relies on input. Is there any way I can have these methods only run once? I am new to programming and this website so I apologize if this question is unclear or has already been asked.

```
     public static int input()
{
    System.out.println("Please enter amount of change under 100 cents: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int change = input.nextInt();
    if (change%5<2)
    {
        change = change+(change%5);
    }
    else if(change%5>2)
    {
        change = change-(change%5);
    }
    return change;

}
public static int[] maxQuarters()
{
    int change = input();
    int quarters = change/25;
    int leftover = change-quarters;
    return new int[] {quarters, leftover};
}
public static int[] maxDimes()
{
    int first[] = maxQuarters();
    int change = first[1];
    int dimes = change/10;
    int leftover = change-dimes;
    return new int[] {dimes, leftover};  
}
public static int maxNickels()
{
    int second[] = maxDimes();
    int change = second[1];
    int nickels = change/5;
    return nickels;
}
public static void makeChange()
{
    int first[] = maxQuarters();
    int quarters = first[0];
    int second[] = maxDimes();
    int dimes = second[0];
    int nickels = maxNickels();
    System.out.println("The minimum number of coins you could use is: "+quarters+"quarters, "+dimes+" dimes and "+nickels+" nickels");

}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    makeChange();
}
```

Comment: Call `input()` *once*, e.g. in `main`, and pass the value using parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asked for input three times, because you call `input()` inside of `maxQuarters()`.
In `maxDimes()` and `maxNickels()` you call `maxQuarters()` and so also `input()` is called.

A possible way to solve this is to call `input()` in your `main`-method and pass the input as parameter to your other methods like this:

```
public static int input() {
    System.out.println("Please enter amount of change under 100 cents: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int change = input.nextInt();
    if (change % 5 < 2) {
        change = change + (change % 5);
    } else if (change % 5 > 2) {
        change = change - (change % 5);
    }
    return change;

}

public static int[] maxQuarters(int input) {

    int quarters = input / 25;
    int leftover = input - 25*quarters;
    return new int[]{quarters, leftover};
}

public static int[] maxDimes(int input) {
    int first[] = maxQuarters(input);
    int change = first[1];
    int dimes = change / 10;
    int leftover = change - 10*dimes;
    return new int[]{dimes, leftover};
}

public static int maxNickels(int input) {
    int second[] = maxDimes(input);
    int change = second[1];
    int nickels = change / 5;
    return nickels;
}

public static void makeChange(int input) {
    int first[] = maxQuarters(input);
    int quarters = first[0];
    int second[] = maxDimes(input);
    int dimes = second[0];
    int nickels = maxNickels(input);
    System.out.println("The minimum number of coins you could use is: " + quarters + " quarters, " + dimes + " dimes and " + nickels + " nickels");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input = input();
    makeChange(input);
}
```